# Does flooding with bytes cause buffer overflow?

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, buffer-overflow, c, exploit-development

If I flood a C program with bytes can I cause buffer overflow, or is there other stuff I have to take into account?

Comment: 1) Describe what exactly you mean by flooding. 2) Describe what exactly you program is doing. If it has no open ports, then it doesn't matter what you do, it will run without any problems.

Comment: @mentallurg what I mean by flooding is for example using pythons socket module to flood the open port that the program runs on with bytes. Would that cause buffer overflow?

Comment: Would that cause buffer overflow? Not necessarily. It depends on how the program is implemented. For instance, Apache HTTP Server is written in C. Nginx is written in C. They remain stable even if you flood them with arbitrary data. So it depends on the program.

Comment: @mentallurg so that would only work if the developer of the program made a mistake? Is this only way to cause buffer overflow, by flooding the port.

Comment: Yes. Either developer didn't care about this at all (e.g. because he didn't know about the problem). Or he cared, but made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flooding bytes is one thing but how are you going to do it? There are many takes on this.

There are generally two types of buffer overflows, through the stack or through the heap. The **most common** one of all would be through the stack which can be illustrated in the answer of this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6220212/buffer-overflow-in-c) and in this [site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/buffer-overflow-attack-with-example/) (using c) both using c to illustrate.

This [site](https://dhavalkapil.com/blogs/Buffer-Overflow-Exploit/) also does a really good job of illustrating and **breaking down** the flow of the exploit, also using c.

It talks about the,

- Memory Layout of a C program and how it runs, (if you can grasp this concept well, half the battle would be already won)
- Common & Key registers
- Memory Management during function calls
- How the vulnerability is exploited on the low-level codes of C/C++ (which c functions are vulnerable to the exploit)
- Designing respective *payloads*

Comment: so can I use python to send a bunch of bytes to the open port that the program runs on and I have caused buffer overflow?

Comment: @user233883 - that entirely depends on the program receiving those bytes. If the developer of that program made a mistake, yes it's possible.